# Get total number of rows when offset is greater than max

Tags: postgresql, select, count, offset-fetch

I have a table `users` that has, say, 42 records. To get the total rows and some other details, I use a window function:

```
select count(*) over() as count, name, id from users
```

And since the consumer app is paginated, I can utilise `limit` and `offset` to get the desired data:

```
select count(*) over() as count, name, id from users limit 5 offset 20
```

This gives me a (sample) result:

```
 count |  name   | id
-------+---------+----
    42 | Dummy05 | 27
    42 | Dummy06 | 30
    42 | Dummy07 | 31
    42 | Dummy08 | 32
    42 | Dummy09 | 33
(5 rows)
```

Of course, this can be optimised as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130331/1500851).

However when the offset value overshoots, I get 0 rows which is correct.

```
select count(*) over() as count, name, id from users limit 5 offset 50
```

Is there a way that gives me the total count despite the offset returning 0 rows? Something on the similar lines:

```
 count |  name   | id
-------+---------+----
    42 |         | 
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt something like this:

```
select c.count, u.*
from
  (
    select count(*) as count
    from users
  ) as c
  left join 
  (
    select name, id
    from users
    order by id
    limit 5 offset 50
  ) as u
  on true
order by u.id
 ;
```